# Edit custom templates selector

Tags: wordpress

I trying to organize custom page templates on directories and subdirectories, but i can't make that wordpress recognize them.

I already have a recursive function to get associative array with template path as a key and template name as a value, and modifiying wp cache, the page template selector catch them, but when page is saved, the post meta contains other template ;(

**Get templates function**

```
function get_custom_templates($path = null, $templates = array()) {
    $parent = "";
    if (is_null($path))
        $path = get_stylesheet_directory() . "/custom_templates";
    else 
        $parent = basename($path);

    foreach (scandir($path) as $item) {
        if (substr($item, 0, 1) == ".") continue;

        $template = $path . "/" . $item;
        if (is_dir($template)) {
            $templates = array_merge($templates, get_custom_templates($template, $templates));
        } else {
            $templates[$template] = $parent . "-" . basename($template, ".php");
        }
    }

    return $templates;
}
```

**Add them to Editor**

```
function include_custom_templates($atts) {
    $cache_key = "page_templates-" . md5(get_theme_root() . "/" . get_stylesheet());

    $templates = wp_get_theme()->get_page_templates();
    if (empty($templates))
        $templates = array();

    wp_cache_delete($cache_key, "themes");
    $templates = array_merge($templates, get_custom_templates());
    wp_cache_add($cache_key, $templates, "themes", 1800);

    return $attrs;
}

add_filter("page_attributes_dropdown_pages_args", "include_custom_templates");
add_filter("wp_insert_post_data", "include_custom_templates");
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Page Templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/#file-organization-of-page-templates):

> WordPress recognizes the subfolder page-templates. Therefore, it’s a good idea to store your global page templates in this folder to help keep them organized.

It's been like that since [WP 3.4](https://nacin.com/2012/03/29/page-templates-in-subdirectories-new-in-wordpress-3-4/).

So my advice is to place them in `/page-templates` subdirectory in your theme, rather than `/custom_templates`. That way, you'll have WordPress recognize them immediately.

Comment: Yes, i know that, but this feature not allow subdirectories inside it. My template has a custom type with many views.